# Jest - module exports / deconstructing causing requireActual to not work or not being able to intercept original method for mocking?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I've got a controller that calls two functions and in one test I would like to see if the child function is called and in my second test see if it returns the correct number.

```
// ./utilities/sayMyName.js

exports.sayMyName = (name) => name;

// ./utilities/doubleNum.js

exports.doubleNum = (num) => num * 2;

// ./utilities/index.js

const { doubleNum } = require("./doubleNum");
const { sayMyName } = require("./sayMyName");

module.exports = {
  doubleNum,
  sayMyName,
};

// myController.js

const { doubleNum, sayMyName } = require("./utilities");

exports.doubleMyNum = (num, name) => {
  const myName = sayMyName(name);
  return doubleNum(num);
};

// myController.test.js

const myController = require("./myController");
const utilities = require("./utilities");

jest.mock("./utilities");

describe("doubleNum", () => {
  test("should call sayMyName", () => {
    myController.doubleMyNum(2, "test name");
    expect(utilities.sayMyName).toHaveBeenCalledWith("test name");
  });

  test("should double my number", () => {
    const { doubleNum } = jest.requireActual("./utilities");
    expect(myController.doubleMyNum(2, "test name")).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

First test passes however it's the second one that fails because I originally mocked the `utilities` module, I followed the docs and using `jest.requireActual` should bring back the original function but it isn't. I did read that mapping the exports like I did in `index.js` and using deconstructing can cause issues with intercepting a function to mock it. How can I go about getting this to work?

### SORTED

After much reading and testing I'd like to think I've sorted the issue by realising that I was trying to change the implementation of function from `index.js` that was already imported into the `myController.js` file that contained the function I was testing

So for example if I want to change the implementation of only one of the exported functions from my `index.js` file I need to mock the module and **reimport** `myController.js` for it to have an affect. So this works:

```
const myController = require("./myController");
const utilities = require("./utilities");

jest.mock("./utilities");

describe("doubleNum", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  test("should call sayMyName", () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(utilities, "sayMyName");
    myController.doubleMyNum(2, "test name");
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("test name");
  });

  test("should double my number", () => {
    jest.mock("./utilities", () => {
      const { sayMyName, doubleNum } = jest.requireActual("./utilities");

      return {
        sayMyName,
        doubleNum,
      };
    });

    // Reimport myController for the actual utilities module to be restored
    const myController = require("./myController");

    expect(myController.doubleMyNum(2, "test name")).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

Of course this could be simplified had I not used deconstruction in `myController.js`, hopefully someone else finds this helpful.

Comment: Could you create a repo or something like that where the issue is reproduced?

Comment: Sure thing - https://github.com/JohnMarsden24/jest-testing

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because you aren’t doing the mocking in a `beforeEach` or `beforeAll` block.
Alternatively, you can look at the `resetModules` example here, and mock or require the module within each `test` block instead of for all tests: [jest.resetModules](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules)

Comment: I've tried every order of reseting modules and the only way I can get it to work is by not requiring the utilities via deconstructing in myController.js and instead requiring the utilities object and calling the functions from it.

Comment: Hey I found a solution and updated my post with it.